# Firebase/Flutter : Get key after pushing

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the firebase key after pushing the data, and this is what I have tried :

```
  var store = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  String newkey = store.reference().child("users/"+defaultState+"/"+defaultCity).push().key;
  store = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users/"+defaultState+"/"+defaultCity);
  print(newkey);
  store.push().set({
      "name": name.text,
      "address": address.text,
      "phone": phone.text,
      "state": defaultState,
      "city": defaultCity,
    }).then((_) {
    }).catchError((onError) {
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(onError)));
    });
```

But for some reason, the `newkey`does not match the key that has been inserted after pushing.Please help

Comment: Where is the key that you are adding after `push()`?

Comment: Can you `newkey `? Do you get any key there? Maybe your code after that is not using the key correctly.

Comment: I have just editted

Comment: I am not sure but I noticed you used store.reference() . reference() used twice

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `push()` twice.

```
String newkey = store.reference().child("users/"+defaultState+"/"+defaultCity).push().key;
```

The above code will generate a random key for you, but it will not add it to the json tree. To add it, you have to do the following:

```
 store.child(newkey).set({
      "name": name.text,
      "address": address.text,
      "phone": phone.text,
      "state": defaultState,
      "city": defaultCity,
    }).then((_) {
    }).catchError((onError) {
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(onError)));
    });
```